# How to move images from bottom to top continuously?

Tags: android

I've been working on the example from http://obviam.net/index.php/a-very-basic-the-game-loop-for-android/ In this I want to make few changes.

**Speed.java**

```
public class Speed {

    public static final int DIRECTION_RIGHT = 1;
    public static final int DIRECTION_LEFT  = -1;
    public static final int DIRECTION_UP    = -1;
    public static final int DIRECTION_DOWN  = 1;

    private float xv = 1;   // velocity value on the X axis
    private float yv = 1;   // velocity value on the Y axis

    private int xDirection = DIRECTION_RIGHT;
    private int yDirection = DIRECTION_DOWN;

    public Speed() {
        this.xv = 1;
        this.yv = 1;
    }

    public Speed(float xv, float yv) {
        this.xv = xv;
        this.yv = yv;
    }

    public float getXv() {
        return xv;
    }
    public void setXv(float xv) {
        this.xv = xv;
    }
    public float getYv() {
        return yv;
    }
    public void setYv(float yv) {
        this.yv = yv;
    }

    public int getxDirection() {
        return xDirection;
    }
    public void setxDirection(int xDirection) {
        this.xDirection = xDirection;
    }
    public int getyDirection() {
        return yDirection;
    }
    public void setyDirection(int yDirection) {
        this.yDirection = yDirection;
    }

    // changes the direction on the X axis
    public void toggleXDirection() {
        xDirection = xDirection * -1;
    }

    // changes the direction on the Y axis
    public void toggleYDirection() {
        yDirection = yDirection * -1;
    }

}
```

Using this, the image moves in all directions. Now I just want to limit this movement from bottom to top. And the functionality for onclick is that, we can click and drag the image to required position. I want to replace that with just make the image to disappear or go to another activity. Please help me in making changes to this code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i want to know too... Please help...

Comment: Replace `private float xv = 1;` with `private float xv = 0;` ?

Comment: @SherifelKhatib that didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

if you have used SurfaceView then in `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method the code is for moving image from bottom to top is something  like this.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,xPoint,yPoint,paint);
```

where bitmap is an image(Bitmap which you want to move),xPoint is the x coordinate,yPoint is the y coordinate and paint is a Paint which is also can be null.

and for bottom to top movement just update

```
yPoint = yPoint - 1;
```

in any thread before `onDraw()` call.

May this help you.

Comment: what about the onclick functionality?

Comment: You can do this in onTouchEvent by finding the coordinates of image and touch coordinates.

Comment: Please check the tutorial and answer accordingly. When I change as u told, it still moves in a cross way from bottom to top and on reaching top, the bitmaps move from left to right or left to right on the top of the screen. So please check the tutorial once and then answer and I know what to do, but not how to do. That is why I'm here. So please answer appropriately if you know. And thanks for atleast turning up to answer the question. thanks again