# How to make image to move from bottom to top on webpage

Tags: javascript, css, image, joomla, transition

I see that this question has come up before, but it did not help me that much.

On my webpage I want an image, a small airballon, to move slowly upp from the right bottom and to stop some place beside my logo, just one time.
http://www.butik.meisolle.com/

I found some code in other posts that I maybe will be able to change so it fits my needs. But where to put this code? I have a Joomla site. 
I am not a programmer, just did the website my self and learned a bit a long the process.

I don't even know if this is possible :-)

/Christina

Comment: Can you link to the previous questions that did not help you, and give examples of the code you want. A look in the Joomla documentation should show you where to put bespoke CSS / Javascript. Try some basic joomla tutorials.

Comment: Hi Ruskin yes I thought I could change in this code he got http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878451/how-to-move-images-from-bottom-to-top-continuously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the hot air balloon to rise a single time, just after the page has loaded?

You should be able to do this with `css` `animation` and `@keyframes`:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="hotairballoon"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hotairballoon {
position:absolute;
top: 0;
left: 200px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 50%;
background: rgba(255,0,0,1);
animation: propel-balloon 10s linear;
}

@keyframes propel-balloon {

    0% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left: 1000px;
    }

    25% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 400px;
    left: 1000px;
    }

    50% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 250px;
    left: 900px;
    }

    75% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 400px;
    }

    100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 200px;
    }
}
```

**N.B.** I've styled the `<div>` with

```
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 50%;
background: rgba(255,0,0,1);
```

for the sake of example, but you'll want to replace the `width:` and `height:` values with the correct dimensions of the image, delete the `border-radius:` declaration and replace

```
background: rgba(255,0,0,1);
```

with something like:

```
background: url('/path/to/hot-air-balloon-image.png') 0 0 no-repeat;}
```

Comment: Hi Rounin yes just one time when you come to my site :), but where to put this code? In my css file? ps. I can see that someone gave me a minus for not researching on this. I really did that allready, that is not fair :-( I just don't know how to do this code, as I said I'm not a programmer, just a stupdid newbe.

Comment: I think you should ignore any question downvotes on StackOverflow, @sky - I'm not persuaded there's such a thing as a "bad" question. And don't worry about not being a programmer! I've been writing websites since 1997 and I wouldn't refer to myself as a programmer. Yes, the CSS just goes in the CSS file!

Comment: Hi again I added the code fromm my template settings. But now I got a blank website. Any ideas what could have gone rong? I changed the width to my image settings. And the background url to url('/images/hotairballoon.png')

Comment: If you now have a blank website, you either have a syntax error in your .css file or else you have a style clash. To avoid any style clashes, place the above styles - temporarily at least - at the very end of your stylesheet. Then scour your .css file for syntax errors.